# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not find a bug in the controller that was previously working normally.
The error message refers to line 23. (*TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*)

```
$scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length;
```

Here is a complete script

```
var appMembers = angular.module('myAppMembers', ['ui.bootstrap']);

appMembers.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    };
    return [];
}
});
appMembers.controller('membersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http({method: "GET", url: "../angularJS/ajax/getMembers.php"})
.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var members = response.members;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    $scope.list = members;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
})
.catch(function onError(response) {
    var members = response.members;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    console.log(response);
});
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() { 
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
});
```

File paths and names (appMembers, myAppMembers) are correct.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `list` is undefined so most likely `members` is undefined in `onSuccess`. You can debug this and easily find out.

Comment: replace ```$scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length``` with ```$scope.filteredItems = $scope.list ? $scope.list.length : 0``` solves this but the main problem is that $scope.list is undefined, if it is usual set ```$scope.list = []``` when it is undefined.

Comment: data comes under `response.data.members` not `response.members`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `$scope.list.length` with `members.length`. And to make sure the `members` is really an array, try to check it by making an output of `response` value into `json`.

```
console.log("response : " + JSON.stringify(response));
```